# business object java program could not instantiate class

Tags: java, business-objects

I made a simple java program that works well in Eclipse and from the console in a jar.

I installed that same jar on Business Object Central Management Console.

The program run successfully but all is printed when I click the instance is:

```
Could not instantiate VersionManager
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: VersionManager
```

Any idea ? I've look somewhere that my main class have to implements `IProgramBase` which I added + the method run, but without success.

Thanks, Elliot

I'm pretty sure that's not code involved... I tested with a simple jar containing one class Test.java :

```
     package com.tranme.businessobject;

     import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.exception.SDKException;
     import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.IEnterpriseSession;
     import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.infostore.IInfoStore;
     import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.plugin.desktop.program.IProgramBase;

     public class Test implements IProgramBase {

     @Override
     public void run(IEnterpriseSession arg0, IInfoStore arg1, String[] arg2)
        throws SDKException {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("this is the TEST");
     }

    }
```

And I still get the same error...

```
Could not instantiate Test
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test
```

Comment: 1.log in CMC.
2. choose my folder , tab object
3. new object, program/java

Comment: What is VersionManager? Are you using external jars?

Comment: VersionManager is my main class in my jar

Comment: Ok, can you post your code?

Comment: Try it without the package declaration.

Comment: Worked without the package declaration thanks ! , would you like to make a real answer so I can give you reputation for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to either remove the package specification from the source, or include the full specification (package name plus class name) for the "Class to run" in the CMC.